# MenuItem.Icon from Resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons, resx

is there a shorter way to get the icon from a resourceassembly? Something like the way for the Header property?

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static resx:Resource.Menue_Menue}">
  <MenuItem Header="{x:Static resx:Resource.Menue_Exit}" Command="{Binding ExitProgramCommand}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
      <Image>
        <Image.Source>
          <BitmapImage UriSource="/Blubb.Resources;component/Icons/IconExit.ico" />
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
  </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `MenuItem` inside `MenuItem`? Is that right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1763797/4112271

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman yes that's right. I use this for nested menuitems.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can remove some code and have the same result:

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static resx:Resource.Menue_Exit}" Command="{Binding ExitProgramCommand}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Icons/IconExit.ico" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Okay, that's shorter. Thanks.

Seem it is not easy to shorten it the way it is possible for the "Header".