# How to set an Icon in a ContextMenu's MenuItem when using ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem, controltemplate

So I have a `Context Menu` And a `MenuItem` in it which breaks out into a list of names:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Set As Default For" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Names}}">
       <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value={Binding Name}/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.DoSomething}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
            </Style>
         </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
     </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Now the above code works file and displays my list of names. Now I would like to add an Icon next to each Name using a Pack URI.. So from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763763/wpf-menu-item-with-image) I can see the best way to do it is to template the `Header` so I tried that first like the question

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Set As Default For" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Names}}">
       <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                         <StackPanel>
                               <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/MyProj;component/Resources/MyImg.png" />
                              <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" />
                          </StackPanel>
                     </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
                 <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.DoSomething}" />
                 <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
            </Style>
         </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
     </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

but this gave me the error:

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
>   Disconnect it first.

So I after some research I tried:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Set As Default For" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Names}}">
       <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                         <ControlTemplate>
                             <StackPanel>
                                   <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/MyProj;component/Resources/MyImg.png" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" />
                              </StackPanel>
                           </ControlTemplate>
                     </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
                 <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.DoSomething}" />
                 <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
            </Style>
         </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
     </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

But now all my names are ControlTemplate and no icon is displayed...

How do I add an icon to a Context Menu's Menu Item through ItemContainerStyle?

**EDIT**

I've tried:

```
   <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
   <Setter Property="Icon">
       <Setter.Value>
           <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/MyProj;component/Resources/MyImg.png" />
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

And I get an icon rendering but only for the last item in my menu?

Comment: Either use `HeaderTemplate` instead of `Header` and use `DataTemplate` instead of `ControlTemplate` but personally I would set `Icon` property as another `Setter` in your `Style`. Your code will place icon in the content part of `MenuItem`, not the `Icon` part

Comment: @dkozl you are right using `HeaderTemplate` and `DataTemplate` worked. And you were also right in that my code placed the icon inside the Header which wasn't what I'd planned. Do you know how to set the icon using Pack URI in a style?

Comment: try setting [`x:Shared`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) to false against your `Style` like `<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Shared="False">`

Comment: @dkozl I can't seem to find the `x:shared` attribute on my style?

Comment: Sorry, it can be applied only to items in `ResourceDictionary`. You need to move `Style` to `ContextMenu.Resources` with some `x:Key` and set `ItemContainerStyle` as `StaticResource`. Also make sure you set `x:Shared` not `x:shared`

Comment: I get the error: `Shared attribute in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries.` at runtime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use one visual in more then one place. You can do it either by using `HeaderTemplate` instead of `Header`, but use `DataTemplate` instead of `ControlTemplate`

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
   <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
               <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/MyProj;component/Resources/MyImg.png" />
               <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <!-- other setters -->
</Style>
```

Note that this solution will put icon in the content part of `MenuItem`, not the icon. Another solution is to set `Icon` property of `MenuItem` as another `Setter` but in this case `Image` needs to 
be separate `Resource` with `x:Shared` set to false otherwise you'll end up with the same problem where only last item has an icon.

```
<ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu.Resources>
      <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/MyProj;component/Resources/MyImg.png" x:Key="myMenuIcon" x:Shared="False" />
   </ContextMenu.Resources>
   <MenuItem Header="Set As Default For" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Names}}">
      <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource myMenuIcon}"/>
         </Style>
      </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
   </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I've copied the second example using the `x:Shared` attribute but I still get the error `Shared attribute in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries.` at runtime. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I've tested that. Against which element do you set `x:Shared`? It shoukld be set against _myMenuIcon_ only, which is in `ContextMenu.Resources`

Comment: It's set against `myMenuIcon` my project is a `plugin` which is a `.dll` and loaded into my application at runtime... that may affect it? my error is being thrown back up to my main application

Comment: @user1 You have to put it into the `<Window.Resources>`. Then you can apply a Binding on the Source and voilla, dynamic icons in the right place :)